# iBeacon name not displayed in ESP32 BLE scanner

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-ide, esp32

I am working on a project that involves a BLE scanner using ESP32. I use the installed BLE scanner sample code in Arduino IDE to program the ESP32 but the device is unable to scan for the names of iBeacon just like any normal android BLE scanner application. I also tried to modify the code to specifically extract the names of iBeacons only but I still end up with the same result. Any suggestions are welcomed. Here is my modified code:

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEScan.h>
#include <BLEAdvertisedDevice.h>

int scanTime = 5; //In seconds
BLEScan* pBLEScan;

class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks: public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks {
    void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice) {
      //Serial.printf("Advertised Device: %s \n", advertisedDevice.toString().c_str());
      Serial.print("Name :");
      Serial.println(advertisedDevice.getName().c_str());
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Scanning...");

  BLEDevice::init("");
  pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan(); //create new scan
  pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks());
  pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true); //active scan uses more power, but get results faster
  pBLEScan->setInterval(100);
  pBLEScan->setWindow(99);  // less or equal setInterval value
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  BLEScanResults foundDevices = pBLEScan->start(scanTime, false);
  Serial.print("Devices found: ");
  Serial.println(foundDevices.getCount());
  Serial.println("Scan done!");
  pBLEScan->clearResults();   // delete results fromBLEScan buffer to release memory
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: `with the same result`, what does it means? does your callback function get called or not at all? Make sure your Serial Monitor setting set to "Both NL & CR".

Comment: What I mean in "with the same result" is that the serial monitor is unable to display the names of iBeacons. However, I manage to solve this problem by moving this portion of code to the void loop () content `pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan(); //create new scan
  pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks());
  pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true); //active scan uses more power, but get results faster`

Comment: Still, thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Kevin.... I've come up against this too... I tried moving the section of code you mention above, but it still doesn't work... Did you fix it?